# filter {dplyr} using a vector instead of a single value

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a dataset of, say, 150 countries from which I would like to select records of, for instance, 50 countries that I already have a vector of. How can I filter needed countries? It's troubling to repetitively use `|` like:

```
filter(mydata, country == "A" | country == "B")
```

Recommendation much appreciated.

Comment: `filter(mydata, country %in% country_vec)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%in%`.

An example data set:

```
mydata <- data.frame(country = LETTERS[1:10])
#    country
# 1        A
# 2        B
# 3        C
# 4        D
# 5        E
# 6        F
# 7        G
# 8        H
# 9        I
# 10       J
```

Vector of letters:

```
vec <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

The code:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(mydata, country %in% vec)
#   country
# 1       A
# 2       B
# 3       C
```